# WHY I got 'The background agent can’t use ScheduledActionService::Add' while submitting my app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I added a background agent in my app. When I try to submit it to the market, I got the following error:

2011: The background agent can’t use Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler.ScheduledActionService::Add, which assembly XXX.Core.dll is trying to use. Update your file and then try again.

Can anyone tell me what's the exact error? How can I modify it?

FYI, I did not add background agent in the XXX.Core.dll by using ScheduledActionService.Add(PeriodicTask). I did it in MainPage.xaml.cs, which is not in the XXX.Core.dll.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thank goodness. I found the exact reason.

The background agent component(XXX.ScheduledTasks.dll) references the XXX.Core.dll, and there are some code using 'ScheduledActionService.Add' in XXX.Core.dll.

After removing the related code from XXX.Core.dll, it's passed.